# Remove borders winforms and WindowState Maximized without fullscreen

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following trouble and i don't find a solution.

I want to implement a Winform without top bar and if is possible, without borders. I tried several things without success, the following would do the trick perfectly :

```
        this.Text = string.Empty;
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
```

producing the following result :

[image: All work perfect ! But when i make it in maximized state]

The little problem is when me or the user trigger the maximize state , because will make the form enter in a FULLSCREEN mode ! and i don't know how to prevent this:

[image: See ? You can't see the windows taskbar !]

See? You can't see the windows taskbar ! I'm using

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; // Makes a fullscreen that i dont want !
```

Appreciate your help !

Comment: What about `this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;` ?

Comment: this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; //when i trigger the maximize state still showing in fullscreen mode :\

Comment: Isn't there is a Windows setting somewhere for taskbar to be always on top. Without it set maximized window will always use desktop working area (**including** taskbar).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this to set size dynamically, it may helps you.

Do not use `WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;`
Try this code on loading form

```
var rectangle = ScreenRectangle();
Size = new Size(rectangle.Width - 100, rectangle.Height - 100);
Location = new Point(50, 50);
// here 100 is pixel used to reserve from edges, 
// you can set lower value according to your requirements
```

For full size

```
var rectangle = ScreenRectangle();
Size = new Size(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
Location = new Point(0, 0);
```

Screen Rectangle Method is:

```
public Rectangle ScreenRectangle()
{
    return Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , it help me to understand a little more what i'm doing ;) , I give the final answer to solve this , but i'll accept your answer !

Answer (score 11):

Well ! Thanks to all your answers I finally solved with the following two methods

```
    private void MaximizeWindow() 
    {
        var rectangle = Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        Size = new Size(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
        Location = new Point(0, 0);
        Rectangle workingRectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
        this.Size = new Size(workingRectangle.Width, workingRectangle.Height);
    }

    private void ResizableWindow() 
    {
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
    }
```

Thanks to X-TECH and Luïs , this was solved !

[image: Maximized state and the taskbar still there !]

Answer (score 2):

Remove the border

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

---

I think this goes work by clicking the maximize button

```
// Add following namespaces
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

// Retrieve the working rectangle from the Screen class using the PrimaryScreen and the 
// WorkingArea properties.
Rectangle workingRectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;

// Set the size of the form slightly less than size of working rectangle. 
this.Size = new Size(workingRectangle.Width, workingRectangle.Height);
```

<sup>Sources: [MSDN `system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Remove the title bar in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482922/remove-the-title-bar-in-windows-forms)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *take control* over *form maximization*, do it like that:

```
  public class MyForm {
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
      const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
      const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;

      // When form is going to be maximized    
      if ((m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND) && (m.WParam.ToInt32() == SC_MAXIMIZE)) {
        m.Msg = 0; // <- we don't want a standard maximization
        //TODO: tell Windows here what to do when user want to maximize the form

        // Just a sample (pseudo maximization)
        Location = new Point(0, 0);
        Size = new Size(Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Width,
                        Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height);
      }

      base.WndProc(ref m);
    } 
    ...
  }
```

Comment: this one doesnt work for me, it never pass that If-then

Answer (score 1):

hi you can to do this only with 2 instructions:
       this.MaximumSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

Comment: Your answer will only put the windows to a maximized state which is not what the question is about.

Answer (score -2):

```
this.Text = string.Empty;
this.ControlBox = false;
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;

this.Left = this.Top = 0;
this.Height = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height;
this.Width = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Width;
```

**GetWorkingArea**: Gets the working area of the display. The working area is the desktop area of the display, **excluding taskbars**, docked windows, and docked tool bars.[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @Luïs, Try run the code, That's work perfectly, Why you think that's not work?

Comment: Oke, I have test it and it work. I didn't know that. sorry for my mistake.