# How to remove the title bar in C# when the form become max()?

Tags: c#

I made my form as Form Border Style= None,but after max() function or Min() function form is loaded with title bar.I don't need title bar at all time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHD5D.png)

Comment: Please specify context, WinForm? WebForm? WPF????

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen .

Comment: am using Winform

Comment: looks like problem in your code. try to search your solution for `FormBorderStyle` modifications. Check this debugging guide, it can help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/06/26/7-lesser-known-hacks-for-debugging-in-visual-studio/?utm_source=vs_developer_news&utm_medium=referral

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Winforms? If you are, try this:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7483026/6441416

[Remove the title bar in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482922/remove-the-title-bar-in-windows-forms)

Comment: i tried this ,but from  minimize  form to maximize window the title bar appear as i mention as image at my question

Answer (score 0):

Add a menu strip to the MDI parent and set it to `visible = false`.

The following code is a bit hacky but I am doing this in the MDI form's load event handler.

```
public partial class MDIParent1 : Form
{    
    public MDIParent1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MDIParent1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form childForm = new Form();
        childForm.MdiParent = this;
        childForm.Text = "Child Window";

        childForm.Show();   

        this.MainMenuStrip = new MenuStrip();
        this.MainMenuStrip.Visible = false;
    };
}
```