# Title bar not disappearing

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar, titlebar

If you are just now reading this, skip to EDITx5 portion of this post.

When I do the following things, the winform title bar does not disappear and instead hides itself behind and/or underneath the taskbar:

EDITx2 (changed the step order):

1. Setting the windows 10 screen resolution to 1920x1080.
2. Right click windows 10 task bar -> open task bar settings -> set 'Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode' to ON.
3. In winform constructor: `this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;`
4. program a minimizing and maximizing functionality for window automatically via a timer event.
5. Run the app.
6. Set the windows 10 screen resolution to 1280x800 while app is running.
7. Notice that there is a short-sized title bar placed behind task bar while the app is running when the app window is minimized.

What is weird is when I do the following, the above scenario does not happen and the title bar is hidden at all resolutions but the app is shown via a taskbar icon in the taskbar which is not desired:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
```

The issue is perhaps related to windows needing to always have a window available for certain screen resolutions?

Trying to set all the form autosize, autoscale, etc properties does not work.

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT:

To be more specific, setting `this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;` works but only at some screen resolutions like 1980x1080. If I do steps 1~7, there will be a small title bar placed behind the task bar.

Also, trying the following does not work either:

```
this.ControlBox = false;

this.Text = String.Empty;

this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;

this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

EDITx3:

Actually, initially running app while the screen res is at 1280x800, then minimizing and maximizing the window a few times with a timer event causes the title bar to just randomly appear under taskbar/ when task bar is hidden. I still have not found a solution to this even when doing this:
`this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
 this.ShowInTaskbar = false;`

EDITx4

I apologize for constantly updating this question. Last thing I have discovered. Changing the scaling while the app is running from 125% to 100% makes that title bar randomly appear at the bottom left hand portion of my screen. These properties are set in the construtor:
`this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
 this.ShowInTaskbar = false;`

EDITx5

Set pc resolution to anything (I was at 1920x1080). Set pc scaling setting to 100%. Put this in form constructor:

`this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
 this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
 this.windowedState = formwindowstate.minimized;`

Have a timer minimize and maximize the window state of the form or provide some way to minimize and maximize the form window in a timed manner. Then the title bar will appear randomly in the botton left portion of the screen even though it should be gone by setting the formborderstyle to none. This a bug in winforms? Can anyone else replicate this problem?

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482922/remove-the-title-bar-in-windows-forms/7483032

Comment: @GehanFernando are you referring to the form resize issue?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

After trying multiple things, the simple code that worked was this:

For minimizing:

```
this.windowstate = formwindowstate.minimized;
this.hide();
```

For maximizing:

```
this.windowstate = formwindowstate.maximized;
this.show();
```