# Clickable Screen overlay in C#

Tags: c#, overlay, always-on-top

I am looking for some technologies or ways to create an application which should work like an active (clickable) overlay.

Let's say that we have running application which is always on top. My idea is to create a section on the left or right side of the screen. I'll try to explain in the fast sketch below:

[image]

As seen from the image, not only I want to create overlay which is on top aswel, but I want to adjust screen size for "App running always on top"

Is something like that possible?

If so can you please navigate me to the right direction?

PS: My app should have some clickable elements like radio buttons etc.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like the window that appears when you right click an icon on the Windows taskbar. This is just a Windows Form without titlebar (here you can read how to hide titlebar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7483026/14940782).

Then, you can add `Opacity` or `BackColor` to the form to make it semi transparent or with some color you want. BackColor allows Transparent, by the way.

Comment: hello there, Thanks for responding... does that means I will be able to change resolution for the "always on top" application and put my app next to it?... If yes that would be amazing

Comment: Think yes. It will be a Windows Form, so you of course can do this. The only thing you have to know is how to do that, and this will be your work ; ) Hope this can help you